# Is userstamp valid with Padrino?

Tags: ruby, compatibility, padrino

I am trying to integrate userstamp into one of my projects and have been following the usage guide from https://github.com/delynn/userstamp.

I have added model_stamp to the appropriate class and I have added include UserStamp to my controller.  However, his controller is

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Userstamp
end
```

and my controller is

```
class ApplicationController < Padrino::Application
  include Userstamp
end
```

Is there a compatibility issue with Padrino or am I missing something?

The error message I get is:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/padrino-core-0.12.4/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:244:in `parent': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
from /Users/mattewschwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:486:in `load_missing_constant'
from /Users/mattewschwar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
```

Comment: Seem `UserStamp`'s dependency isn't resolved properly. Can you ensure whether you have *required* it properly?

Comment: It correctly gets added to my Gemfile.lock so I think it does.